# Hypercharge and Isospin as additive quantum numbers in $SU(3)$ flavour symmetry

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, representation-theory, lie-algebra, isospin-symmetry

I am studying the $SU(3)$ flavour symmetry and I'm reading that we use the fact that hypercharge and isospin are additive quantum numbers in order to decompose the tensor products of the fundamental representations $3\otimes3\otimes3$ and $3\otimes{\overline3}$ in the direct sum of the irreducible components.

I don't understand why, from a physical and mathematical points of view, hypercharge and isospin should be additive.

Comment: Hypercharge yes as it is an eigenvalue but isospin is like quantum angular momentum and only one of the components is additive.

Comment: In terms of Gell-Mann matrices, have you inspected the 3 isospin generators and the hypercharge generator? Do they commute? How do they act on the 3 components of a triplet flavor vector?

Answer (score 1):

The (strong) [hypercharge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercharge) operator $Y$ and the (strong) [isospin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin) operators $(I_1,I_2,I_3)$ are generators of a $u(1)\oplus su(2)$ Lie subalgebra of the Lie algebra $su(3)$ of [flavor symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavour_(particle_physics)). A [Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) is a [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), and hence has a linear structure. Representations can be decomposed in eigenspaces for $Y$ and $I_3$.